# Can't use Moneris in React native

Tags: react-native, payment

I want to put credit card number in a field and on clicking a button to retrieve its token. I don't find much information but the thing that I found is:
https://developer.moneris.com/Documentation/NA/E-Commerce%20Solutions/Hosted%20Solutions/Hosted%20Tokenization

I tried with it but still can't make it work. If I put this whole code in webview html part it will call the function on the first screen render. If I try to get the functions out of the webview and use them  I can't take the specific iframe with ***document.getElementById('monerisFrame').contentWindow;***
Any thoughts  how can I accomplish my task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moneris Apis to communicate in React Native :
We can create XML Post Request and connect with the Moneris server with your **API Token** and **Store Id**

Follow this blog :
https://medium.com/me/stats/post/7129b5a8b4a2